# Ave Maria - Gounod Arr. Gerlitz piano fingering right hand

Tags: piano, fingering

I am trying to learn this piece and towards the end there are some chords that I’m trying to find an … elegant? Efficient? Fingering for in the right hand.

Here is a picture.
[image]
I have highlighted the problem areas in yellow.

On the left you can see I start with 1-5 on the G and E. But running down the next three chords (actually four including the start of the next bar) I can’t seem to make anything work other than lifting my whole hand and shifting down for each chord.

Then at the end of that line I do the same with 1-5, 1-5, 1-5, 1-5. (I just found a much better way changing between 2-5 and 1-4. Which allows me to follow the slurs too).

Is there a nicer fingering that I could use for these to make the whole thing nicer to play and more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: Are you playing with or without pedal?

Comment: @Aaron I’m playing with pedal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not perfect I’d maybe go with something along the lines of this:

[image]

In practise this would look like this:
https://petzel.at/gounod.mp4

Comment: Excellent. Trying it out now.

Comment: Also, what software did you use to write that score and fingering? Thanks 

Comment: @Fogmeister https://lilypond.org/

Comment: Ok, this will take some practice but I really like it! Thanks 